# Is this Parathensis in Regex in HTML5 necessary?

Tags: regex, html

The following snippet is from a book on HTML5:

```
<label for="zip">US Zip code</label>
<input id="zip" name="zip" pattern="[\d]{5}(-[\d]{4})">
```

I think the Parathensis in `[\d]{5}(-[\d]{4})` is redundant, which means:
`[\d]{5}(-[\d]{4})` equals to `[\d]{5}-[\d]{4}`

Is it right?

Comment: Until you want to capture it, its useless

Comment: Parenthesis are patterns in regular expressions. That patterns will replace with another content. So it's not a math operator, it's an useful technique.

Comment: For that matter, so are the character classes. It seems the author of the book is just fond of brackets. The pattern can be simplified to `\d{5}-\d{4}` (the curly brackets are the only ones that are actually useful here).

Comment: I think that was probably originally meant for something like `\d{5}(-\d{4})?` because the "+4" is usually optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the character classes in your pattern are rather redundant and may lead to further issues arising from misunderstanding how character classes work.

*Rule of thumb* is not to use something if you do not have to. Thus, "simplify" the pattern to `\d{5}(-\d{4})`.

A pair of unescaped parentheses like that in your pattern is used to [*group* and *capture*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (put a submatch into a memory buffer allocated for each such group).

So, `\d{5}(-\d{4})` matches 5 digits from the start of the string (since the pattern attribute regex is anchored on both sides with `^(?:` and `)$` by default) and then matches and places the hyphen and 4 digits at the end of the string into memory buffer #1 *thus, creating a group that can be referred to with a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)*.

A backreference inside a pattern is specified with `\n` syntax where `n` is the capture group ID. So, to match text that was matched previously in the same pattern we may use these backreferences. It is useful when you need to check for duplicate values in the string. Say, you want to validate strings that start and end with the same 2 digits: `pattern="(\d{2}).*?\1"`:

```html
<form>
 <input pattern="(\d{2}).*?\1" message="2 digits at the start and end should be identical!" />
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Besides, **you can leverage *grouping* (both capturing `(...)` and non-capturing `(?:...)`) to match several occurrences of specific sequences**. Say, you want to match 2 sequences of `abc` + 3 digits. You'd use `(abc\d{3}){2}` then.

Answer (score 1):

round brackets are used for capture group, if you don't use capture groups, it's ok to remove them

To be sure, I tried on this site http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: I think so. But this is HTML5, how can you use a capture group?

Comment: I was checking the official docs (w3c) but can't find how to use capture groups, I think it is always needed some JS to use them

Comment: Parentheses can be used for more than just capturing.